# Do we have to use the capital letter for "I" letter in these case?

Tags: usage, sentence-usage, subjects, ielts

I'm studying for IELTS myself and I have a question about formal writing.

When we use "I" letter in objects and verbs, do we have to use the capital letter even though it's not at the beginning at the sentence?

Case 1 :

> I agree it's....

or

> I agree It's...

Case 2 :

> You know i am....

or

> Can i use like that?

Comment: It looks like the basic issue here is word capitalization rules vs. sentence capitalization rules.  The word "I" is a bad choice to discuss that, since it is always capitalized (answerable with a dictionary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronoun `I` must always be capitalised, whether it's at the start of a sentence or not. There's no real reason why it is capitalised, but it's been that way for around 700 years and so is now the only accepted way for the pronoun to be written. [This EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/why-should-the-first-person-pronoun-i-always-be-capitalized) offers possible origins of the capitalisation of the pronoun `I`.

If the letter `I` is not being used as a pronoun, standard capitalisation rules apply:

- If the letter appears at the start of a sentence:

  > Individual writers write individually.
- If the letter is the first letter of a [proper noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun):

  > The population of India is around 1.3 billion.
- If the letter is part of an [initialism or acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym#Nomenclature), unless that initialism
  or acronym has become so ubiquitous that it is treated as a word rather
  than an acronym/initialism:

  > In 1908, the FBI was founded as the Bureau of Investigation.
  >
  > Zip *[Zone Improvement Plan]* codes are a form of [postal code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code) in the
  >   US.

Answer (score 2):

You always need to capitalize the letter 'i' when using the first person singular pronoun. Thus:

> - I agree it's...
> - You know I am...
> - Can I use like that...

The letter 'i' in the word it's in your Case 1 example above would not be capitalized unless it was the first word in a sentence.

> - It's a great thing that...
> - I think it's a great thing that...